# Is it possible to merge select and drop/delete query together and make it as one in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to merge select and delete/drop query together and make it as one in MySQL. For ex:

```
Select * from t where year = 2015 and drop table tab;
```

or

```
Select * from t where year = 2015 and delete from tab;
```

And ya i'm not allowed to use ';' for merging.

Its Just for some SQL Injection

Comment: You _can't_ do a select and a DML in the same statement.  The closest thing to what you want would be to use a transaction.  Are you trying to take down someone's website?

Comment: ahaan! nope its my own

Comment: why you don't do just a simple `delete from t where year= 2015` ???  select for delete have no sense in sql

Comment: your requirement doesn't make sense

Comment: @Akintunde007 exploitation never makes sense ?

Comment: @scaisEdge delete query is totally unrelated to select query .. The select query its just there

Comment: your comment in SQL code have not sense  ..  the queries you are showing in your question .. t  are sintactically and sematically wrong  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge is this syntactically correct ??
`Select * from t where year = 2015 ; delete from tab;`

Comment: yes ..  the two separated  query are syntactically correct  ..  but for the semantics  you should explain better your goal ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I know this query makes 0 sense..... but then the scenario here is for SQL Injection

Comment: @scaisedge, Tim, I think the OP is trying to recreate the scenario described in the famous xkcd 'bobby tables' cartoon.

Comment: @Strawberry (Y)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't select and drop a table.

you can only join the tables but not queries.